# need to receive the request header data in the react component for the specific route (using React Router v6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angularjs, redirect, authorization

I have two project one is angularjs application and another one is reactjs application. i need to redirect from angular application to the reactjs page on the button click for some specific page.I have backend server in sailsjs that can be used by both application. since the user is logged-in in angular application, i just need to pass the authorisation token from angular to react application while redirecting. I have tried to pass the token through url params but it has security threats.So i need that somehow my angular app make any request to the specific route of the reactapp with authorisation token in its header and I can fetch this token in my react application.

i have tried making get request in angularjs app for some url in react application. but i do not know how to respond to the request in reactjs frontend